# CMake can't find yaml-cpp on debian jessie

Tags: ros, rosdep, debian, jessie, yaml-cpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release a new package on the ROS build farm, and the debian jessie build is currently failing due to the `yaml-cpp` dependency. I have it listed as a dependency in my package.xml:

`<depend>yaml-cpp</depend>`

and the relevant lines in my CMakeLists.txt are:

`find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
catkin_package(
...
DEPENDS YAML_CPP
)
include_directories(
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
add_library(my_target ...)
target_link_libraries(my_target ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})`

On Ubuntu this builds just fine, both locally and on the ROS build farm. For the Debian Jessie build, however, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findyaml-cpp.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "yaml-cpp",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "yaml-cpp" with any
  of the following names:

    yaml-cppConfig.cmake
    yaml-cpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "yaml-cpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "yaml-cpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "yaml-cpp" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The rosdep dependency seems to be resolving just fine (It installs `libyaml-cpp-dev` properly and `rosdep resolve yaml-cpp --os=debian:jessie` returns as expected). However, it seems that either the CMake config file either isn't being installed or is not being found. I'm not sure what to do about this, especially since it works in Ubuntu.

The package that's failing is the "rosflight" package at https://github.com/rosflight/rosflight.git. If you're set up to run [ROS prerelease tests](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest), the error can be reproduced using the following commands:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/prerelease_job
cd /tmp/prerelease_job
generate_prerelease_script.py \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/production/index.yaml \
  kinetic default debian jessie amd64 \
  --custom-repo \
    rosflight:git:https://github.com/rosflight/rosflight-release.git:release/kinetic/rosflight/0.1.2-0 \
    rosflight_msgs:git:https://github.com/rosflight/rosflight-release.git:release/kinetic/rosflight_msgs/0.1.2-0 \
    rosflight_pkgs:git:https://github.com/rosflight/rosflight-release.git:release/kinetic/rosflight_pkgs/0.1.2-0 \
    rosflight_utils:git:https://github.com/rosflight/rosflight-release.git:release/kinetic/rosflight_utils/0.1.2-0 \
  --level 0 \
  --output-dir ./
./prerelease.sh
```

Any insights would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262502/cmake-can%27t-find-yaml-cpp-on-debian-jessie/) by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2017-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-25**:
Is `yam-cpp` a CMake package on Debian? I remember having to use `PkgConfig` like this:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(yaml_cpp REQUIRED yaml-cpp)
```

**Comment by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on 2017-05-25**:
@gvdhoorn That appears to have resolved my issue, thanks! Switching to `PkgConfig` seems to work for both Ubuntu and Debian, although I did have to change from `${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR}` to `${YAML_CPP_INCLUDEDIR}` (I used a `YAML_CPP` prefix instead of `yaml_cpp` in `pkg_check_modules()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per @gvdhoorn's suggestion, this was resolved by switching to `PkgConfig` to find the module. So now instead of `find_package(yaml_cpp REQUIRED)` I have

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(YAML_CPP REQUIRED yaml-cpp)
```

I also needed to modify my include statement slightly to

```
include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDEDIR})
```

where before it was `include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR})`.

This seems to work for both Debian and Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) with karma: 132 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-07-13**:
Ran into this issue building clearpathrobotics/pulson_ros, and this solution worked for us, too.